# Trying to load a script file from my node server - get 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, http-status-code-404

I created a node js server. I'm sending a HTML file that contains the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

My app is arrange like this:

- (dir) server: contains 'app.js'
- (dir) scripts: contains the 'jquery.js'
- (dir) client: contains the html file 'index.html'

The server send the index.html file.
When I'm pressing F12 I'm receiving the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:8080/jquery.js
```

I tried also to change the directory of the jquery file but still it gives me the error.

Any solutions? thanks...

Comment: Can you show the JS code on the server where you serve the HTML file? Also, are you using `Express` ?

Comment: @Drown Yes, i'm using express and the server code is:

app.get('/screen=:sreenNum', function(request, response) {
 response.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/index.html'));
});

Comment: @GuyBen-Shahar — So where did you define the route for `/jquery.js`?

Comment: @Quentin - My server is in root dir (I moved it). The 'jquery.js' file and all the other scripts files is in root/scripts.
I'm still getting 404

Comment: @GuyBen-Shahar — I'm not talking about your *root* directory or your directory paths. I'm talking about the *routes* you've defined in your server side JS.

Comment: @Quentin - sorry, didn't notice the 'u'... I didn't config the routes in the server itself. My server sending the index.html file and the index file loading main.js with routing (using angular)

Comment: @Quentin - this is the code from server:

`app.get("/*", function(request, response) {
 response.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});`

Comment: @GuyBen-Shahar — Not your client side routing. Your Node.js routing. You have code to tell your node.js server what to do if the browser asks for `/screen=:screenNum` but you don't have any for when it asks for `jquery.js`.

Comment: @GuyBen-Shahar — OK, that's different code … so not when the browser asks for *anything*, including when the browser asks for jQuery.js … you give the browser the index.html file.

Comment: You've got a request. You need a route which will give the correct response.

Comment: @Quentin - ok, i think i got it. I must write another request for .js files.
But it doesn't make sence to write for any file a request.
It should know to take the scripts from scripts/... like this:
`<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to serve your static files from the `scripts` directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/javascripts'));
```

than you can retrieve with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If jQuery is in a directory called `scripts`, it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is jquery.js relative to the webserver's root directory? node.js is irrelevant for this.

Comment: Under root i have server directory, client directory and scripts directory

Comment: I even tried to add under client directory 'scripts' directory with jquery file in it and change it according you were saying and it still doesn't work. @Barmar

Comment: The error message you showed suggests `index.html` is in the root directory, not `client`. Because it's looking for `jquery.js` in the same directory as the HTML.

Comment: ok, so maybe the problem is in the server.
This is the request for the index.html
`app.get('/screen=:sreenNum', function(request, response) { response.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/index.html')); });`  @Barmar